# Equality holds in inequality, what is f in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

(1) Find a linear fractional transformation $T$ such that $T(0)=0$, that sends $\{Re(w)<1\}$ to $\{\lvert w \lvert <1\}$.

(2) Suppose $f$ is analytic for $\{\lvert z \lvert <1\}$ and satisfies f(0)=0 and $Re(f(z))<1$, show that $f(z)\leq \frac{2 \lvert z \lvert}{1-\lvert z \lvert} $.

(3) Suppose that the equality in (2) holds for some $z_0$ with $0<z_0<1$. What is $f$ in this case?

I could solve (1) and (2) but I am stuck at (3).
My idea was first to use the maximum modulus principle, so $f$ would be constant, but we don't know if this would hold for all other $z$ on the unit disk. I also thought about using Schwarz's lemma but I don't how I could approach with this. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but, speaking from experience, $f$ should be the inverse of $T$. Could you check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(z) = f(z)/(2-f(z))$ maps the unit disk into itself with $g(0) = 0$. The Schwarz lemma states that
$$
\tag{$*$}
 |g(z)| \le |z|
$$
for all $z$ in the unit disk, and that equality at a single point implies that $g$ is a rotation of the form $g(z) = cz$ with $|c| = 1$.

It follows from $(*)$ that
$$ \tag{$**$}
|f(z)| \le \frac{2|z|}{(1-|z|} \, .
$$
If equality holds in $(**)$ for some $z_0$ then equality holds in $(*)$, and that implies
$$
 \frac{f(z)}{2-f(z)} = c z
$$
for some constant $c$ with $|c| = 1$. You can solve the last equation for $f(z)$ to get the possible functions $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes totally sense. g is actually the map I used to prove (2), but I didn't see that equality holds in (*) if it holds in ('doublestar').